# How can I make comparisons in Wordpress SQL wp_postmeta table between columns meta_key and meta_value?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

Hello I was wondering how can I make comparisons between the `meta_key` and `meta_value` columns found in the `wp_postmeta` table?

**For Example**:

Lets assume that I want to select all the `post_id`'s `WHERE` `_wpml_media_featured` is equal to `1` and `WHERE` `_stock_status` is equal to `instock`.

I used this code:

```
SELECT * FROM `Ab64Zf55_postmeta` WHERE 

(`meta_key` = "_wpml_media_featured" AND `meta_value` = 1 ) 

 AND 

(`meta_key` = "_stock_status" AND `meta_value` = "instock" )
```

[image]

But I got `0` results returned from this query!

**QUESTION**:

- What am I doing wrong or how can I modify my code to get what I need?

*-Thanks in advance for your help!*

Comment: Apologize for ignorance, but I know nothing about wordpress and how that data are structured, but it appears your example is "outofstock" and the query is looking for "instock". What should the result be for this query and sample data?

Comment: Hello @Isolated , Despite the example there are about 50 Thousand products in the database. I just stated I want to retrieve the products that have the status set to instock, no matter the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select all wp_postmeta record with `_wpml_media_featured = 1` or `_stock_status = instock` then `group` the result by `post_id`

```
SELECT post_id FROM Ab64Zf55_postmeta 

WHERE ( meta_key = '_wpml_media_featured' AND meta_value = 1 )

OR ( meta_key = '_stock_status' AND meta_value = 'instock' )

GROUP BY post_id
```

the above query will give you the list of all the unique `post_id`

just remember if you select all column (`SELECT *`), you'll get sql error if `only_full_group_by` is turned `on` in your database engine.

Another method is to `query` the `wp_posts` table first and separately `inner join` the two meta fields, this method allows you to pull the record from wp_posts table like post title

```
SELECT 
    post.ID, 
    post.post_title, 
    wmf.meta_value media_featured, 
    stock.meta_value stock

FROM wp_posts post

INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wmf
    ON  post.ID = wmf.post_id
    AND wmf.meta_key = '_wpml_media_featured'
    AND wmf.meta_value = 1

INNER JOIN wp_postmeta stock
    ON  post.ID = stock.post_id
    AND stock.meta_key = '_stock_status'
    AND stock.meta_value = 'instock'
```